# Запуск приложения из perl с парамтрами

Tags: perl

Добрый день!

У меня есть скрипт, который запускается из CMD следующим образом:

```
perl jpegrescan.pl jpegtran image.jpg image.jpg
```

В jpegrescan.pl есть строчка

```
die "File $fin is not RGB or grayscale\n"
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при возникновении данного условия, происходила обработка изображения со следующими параметрами:

```
jpegtran -copy all -progressive image.jpg image.jpg
```

Собственно сам **jpegrescan.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -ws
# jpegrescan by Loren Merritt
# Last updated: 2008-11-29 / Andrey Chernomyrdin 2012-04-28
# This code is public domain.

sub jpegtran (@) {
    unless(system($ARGV[0], $strip ? ("-copy","none") : ("-copy","all"), @_) == 0) {
        if ($? == -1) {
            die "Error execute jpegtran: $!\n";
        }
        elsif ($? & 128) {
            die sprintf(
                "jpegtran died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
                ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without'
            );
        }
        else {
            die "jpegtran exited with ERRORLEVEL=" . $? >> 8 . "\n";
        }
    }
}

# FIXME optimize order for either progressive transfer or decoding speed
sub canonize {
    my $txt = $prefix.$suffix.shift;
    $txt =~ s/\s*;\s*/;\n/g;
    $txt =~ s/^\s*//;
    $txt =~ s/ +/ /g;
    $txt =~ s/: (\d+) (\d+)/sprintf ": %2d %2d", $1, $2/ge;
    # treat u and v identically. I shouldn't need to do this, but with jpegtran overhead it saves 9% speed. cost: .008% bitrate.
    $txt =~ s/^2:.*\n//gm;
    $txt =~ s/^1:(.+)\n/1:$1\n2:$1\n/gm;
    # dc before ac, coarse before fine
    return join( "\n",
        sort {
            "$a\n$b" =~ /: *(\d+) .* (\d);\n.*: *(\d+) .* (\d);/ or die;
            !$3 <=> !$1 or $4 <=> $2 or $a cmp $b;
        }
        split( /\n/, $txt )
    );
}

sub try {
    my $txt = canonize(shift);
    my $rc;
#    print $txt, "\n\n"; # debug
    if (exists $memo{$txt}) {
        $rc = $memo{$txt};
    }
    else {
        open( my $io, "> $ftmp") or die "Error create $ftmp file: $!\n";
        print $io $txt;
        close $io;
        unlink $fout if (-f $fout);
        jpegtran("-scans", $ftmp, "-outfile", $fout, $jtmp);
        unless ($rc = -s $fout) {
            die "jpegtran output file zero size";
        }
        unless ($quiet) {
            print $verbose ? "$txt\n$rc\n\n" : ".";
        }
        $memo{$txt} = $rc;
    }
    return $rc;
}

sub triesn {
    my ($limit, @modes) = @_;
    my $overshoot = 0;
    my ($bmode, $bsize);
    foreach my $mode (@modes) {
        my $s = try($mode);
        if (!$bsize || $s < $bsize) {
            $bsize = $s;
            $bmode = $mode;
            $overshoot = 0;
        }
        elsif ($limit > 0 and ++$overshoot >= $limit) {
            last;
        }
    }
    return $bmode;
}

sub gen_modes {
    my $c = shift;
    my $str = shift;
    map {
        $_ => sprintf( "$c: 1 %d $str;$c: %d 63 $str;", $_, $_+1)
    } 2,5,8,12,18;
}

sub try_splits {
    my $c = shift;
    my $str = shift;
    my %n = gen_modes($c, $str);
    my $mode = triesn(2, "$c: 1 63 $str;", @n{2,8,5});
    if ($mode ne $n{8}) {
        return $mode;
    }
    else {
        return triesn(1, $mode, @n{12,18});
    }
}

sub get_stderr {
    my $code = shift;
    my $rc;
    if (ref $code eq 'CODE') {
        my $old_stderr;
        open $old_stderr, ">&", STDERR;
        open STDERR, ">", $otmp;
        $code->(@_);
        open STDERR, ">&", $old_stderr;
        $rc = do {
            local $/;
            open(my $io, $otmp);
            <$io>;
        };
        unlink( $otmp ) if (-f $otmp);
    }
    return $rc;
}

# sub main {
unless (scalar @ARGV == 3) {
    die "usage: jpegrescan /path/to/jpegtran.exe in.jpg out.jpg\ntries various progressive scan orders\n";
}

$fin = $ARGV[1];
$fout = $ARGV[2];
$verbose = 0;
$quiet = 0;
$strip = 0;
$ftmp = "$fout-$$.scan";
$jtmp = "$fout-$$.jpg";
$otmp = "$fout-$$.out";
undef $/;
$|=1;
$prefix = "";
$suffix = "";

# convert the input to baseline, just to make all the other conversions faster
# FIXME there's still a bunch of redundant computation in separate calls to jpegtran
my $stderr = get_stderr(
    sub {
        jpegtran("-v", "-optimize", "-outfile", $jtmp, $fin);
    }    
);

if ($stderr =~ /components=(\d+)/) {
    my $rgb;
    if ($1 == 3) {
        $rgb = 1;
        # 012 helps very little
        # 0/12 and 0/1/2 are pretty evenly matched in frequency, but 0/12 wins in total size if every image had to use the same mode
        # dc refinement passes never help
        $dc = triesn(0, "0: 0 0 0 0;1: 0 0 0 0;2: 0 0 0 0;" );
        # jpegtran won't let me omit dc entirely, but I can at least quantize it away to make the rest of the tests faster.
        $prefix = "0 1 2: 0 0 0 9;";
    }
    elsif ($1 == 1) {
        $rgb = 0;
        $dc = "0: 0 0 0 0;";
        $prefix = "0: 0 0 0 9;";
    }
    else {
        die "File $fin is not RGB or grayscale\n"
    }
    foreach my $c ( 0 .. $rgb ) {
        my $max_i = $c ? 2 : 3;
        my $ml = "";
        my @modes;
        my $refine;
        foreach my $i ( 0 .. $max_i ) {
            push @modes, "$c: 1 8 0 $i;$c: 9 63 0 $i;".$ml;
            $ml .= sprintf("$c: 1 63 %d %d;", $i+1, $i);
        }
        $refine = triesn(1, @modes);
        $refine =~ s/.* (0 \d);//;
        $ac .= $refine . try_splits($c, $1);
    }
    # luma can make use of up to 3 refinement passes.
    # chroma can make use of up to 2 refinement passes.
    # refinement passes have some chance of being split (luma: 4%,4%,4%. chroma: 20%,8%) but the total bit gain is negligible.
    # msb pass should almost always be split (luma: 87%, chroma: 81%).
    # I have no theoretical reason for this list of split positions, they're just the most common in practice.
    # splitting into 3 ections is often slightly better, but the total number of bits saved is negligible.
    # FIXME: penalize lots of refinement passes because it's slower to decode. if so, then also force overwrite if bigger than the input.
    $prefix = "";
    %memo = ();
    $mode = $dc.$ac;
    $mode = canonize($mode);
    try($mode);
    $size = $memo{$mode};
    print "\n$mode\n$size\n" unless ($quiet);
    unlink(
        $jtmp,
        $ftmp,
    );
}
else {
    die "Invalud output from jpegtran\n";
}
```

Comment: надо изменить jpegrescan.pl или скрипт который его вызывает ?

Answer (score 2):

Э... Я не очень понял, в чём проблема заменить die на вызов jpegtran с нужными параметрами?

```
jpegtran("-progressive", $fin, $fout);
```

Разбор stderr уже по вкусу.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не знаю perl вообще.
сделал как Вы сказали, Perl выдает:

Use of uninitialized value $rgb in foreach loop entry at C:\Users\Lorents\Desktop\Image Catalyst\Tools\scripts\jpegrescan.pl line 170.ф
Invalid progressive parameters at scan script entry 1 Argument "jpegtran exited with ERRORLEVEL=256" isn't numeric in right bitshift (>>) at C:\Users\Lorents\Desktop\Image Catalyst\Tools\scripts\jpegrescan.pl line 18. 0 at C:\Users\Lorents\Desktop\Image Catalyst\Tools\scripts\jpegrescan.pl line 18.

Comment: С $rgb понятно: как раз в этом else, где и был вызов die, значение этой переменной действительно не определено. Вставьте $rgb=что_нужно; перед вызовом jpegtran(). Больше подсказывать не буду, sorry, отладка и правка чужих исходников - это работа. А если это perl и без use strict, то с надбавкой за вредность :)

Comment: Спасибо! буду разбираться

jpegrescan.pl используется у меня в проекте http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=4&topic=4263

Проект полностью бесплатный, а сейчас есть время дорабатываю потихоньку.

Answer (score 1):

А вам не кажется, что

```
die "File $fin is not RGB or grayscale\n"
```

выводиться не просто так. Это значит, что цветовая модель jpegа, не RGB или оттенки серого, а к примеру LAB или что-угодно ( на чем программа аварийно завершается - die). И для этой цветовой модели не предусмотрены данный алгоритм.

Comment: дело в том, что сам jpegtran прекрасно поддерживает все виды JPEG.
jpegrescan.pl, по сути, некая надстройка над jpegtran, при этом jpegrescan.pl поддерживает только RGB и grayscale, но при этом не поддерживает CMYK. Но сам jpegtran поддерживает CMYK, по этой причине я и хочу убрать это ограничение.